# Definition : Weak Topology , nuance between "continuous" terms.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Definition of weak topology i could find : Let X be a Banach space and X' being it's topological dual. The weak topology over X is the smallest topology such as continuous elements (to the sense of the norm) of X' remains continuous.

Does the last "continuous" refers to the topological sense of continuity ? f is continuous to the topological sense in X' if for all neighborhood V of f(x) with x $\in X$ , $f^{-1}(V)$ is a neighborhood of x.

Comment: Your last sentence is wrong. $f\in X'$ is continuous if for all $V$ open in $\mathbb R$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$.

Comment: You want that, for all $x\in X$ and for all $V$ neighbourhood of $f(x)$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is a neighbourhood of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course this refers to the topological definition of continuity. This continuity depends on the topology of $X$ and that of the scalars (so $\Bbb R$ here).

But it turns out that if $f$ is a functional ( so a linear map to the scalars) then it’s equivalent to be norm continuous or weak continuous.